# Elegant way to remove contiguous repeated elements in a list

Tags: python, list, idioms, python-2.x

I'm looking for a clean, Pythonic, way to eliminate from the following list:

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

all **contiguous repeated elements** (runs longer than one number) so as to obtain:

```
re = [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

but although I have working code, it feels un-Pythonic and I am quite sure there must be a way out there (maybe some lesser known `itertools` functions?) to achieve what I want in a far more concise and elegant way.

Comment: Seem like your result should be:   `re = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`  ?

Comment: @Justin he wants to eliminate groups of length > 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a version based on [Karl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641955/elegant-way-to-remove-contiguous-repeated-elements-in-a-list/7642017#7642017) which doesn't requires copies of the list (`tmp`, the slices, and the zipped list). `izip` is significantly faster than (Python 2) `zip` for large lists. `chain` is slightly slower than slicing but doesn't require a `tmp` object or copies of the list. `islice` plus making a `tmp` is a bit faster, but requires more memory and is less elegant.

```
from itertools import izip, chain
[y for x, y, z in izip(chain((None, None), li),
                       chain((None,), li),
                       li) if x != y != z]
```

A `timeit` test shows it to be approximately twice as fast as Karl's answer or my fastest `groupby` version for short groups.

Make sure to use a value other than `None` (like `object()`) if your list can contain `None`s.

Use this version if you need it to work on an iterator / iterable that isn't a sequence, or your groups are long:

```
[key for key, group in groupby(li)
        if (next(group) or True) and next(group, None) is None]
```

`timeit` shows it's about ten times faster than the other version for 1,000 item groups.

Earlier, slow versions:

```
[key for key, group in groupby(li) if sum(1 for i in group) == 1]
[key for key, group in groupby(li) if len(tuple(group)) == 1]
```

Comment: @JBernardo Edited to use that method because a quick `timeit` says it's a third faster, and you don't have the additional memory use in case `group` is large. Thanks.

Comment: @JBernardo The new version seems to be faster than `sum` for short groups (as well as long) since it doesn't need to create a generator object for each group.

Comment: I admire your continued determination here.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I also realized I never tested your version with long groups -- with 1000 item groups it's 10x slower than my `groupby` / `next` version.

Answer (score 4):

[agf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641955/elegant-way-to-remove-contiguous-repeated-elements-in-a-list/7641976#7641976) is good if the size of the groups is small, but if there are enough duplicates in a row, it will be more efficient not to "sum 1" over those groups

```
[key for key, group in groupby(li) if all(i==0 for i,j in enumerate(group)) ]
```

Comment: That's a good optimization for long groups, but it's 50% slower for short groups. I've added a version to mine that seems to be faster for either long or short groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp = [object()] + li + [object()]
re = [y for x, y, z in zip(tmp[2:], tmp[1:-1], tmp[:-2]) if y != x and y != z]
```

Comment: I'm still trying to see if that's a joke or a really bad solution... BTW, it will only work for some lists

Comment: Removing groups of repeated values is equivalent to keeping non-repeated values, i.e. values which are different from either adjacent value. `tmp` has sentinels at either end that compare false to everything else. I make three lists: the middle one is equivalent to the original, and the others are offset by 1 in each direction. Thus, when I `zip` them to compare them element-wise, it's equivalent to comparing each element in the original list to its two neighbours, and keeping the ones that are different from either neighbour.

Comment: @JBernardo it is not only an entirely serious solution, it is what immediately occurred to me as the way to do it. (Actually, I originally developed something simpler that left unique copies of the repeated elements, and then had to re-read the spec...) I would like to see your example list that it doesn't work on. It works on an empty list, a list containing one `object`, a list containing several unique `object`s, and a list containing several identical `object`s, in my testing.

Comment: Well, I tried later and it works, but it still looks like a joke and a bad solution (readability counts...)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I get it (although I see JBernardo didn't :P), but your answer would be better with an explanation (Edit that into your answer?). Also, note you could use `x != y != z`.

Comment: This is logically very similar to one other implementation I did, although it didn't occur to me to zip the values from the offset lists in a single list, so my code spawned for several lines. I truly like it (and - but this maybe is because I spent some time on the problem - it doesn't seem hard to read either to me). +1! :)

Comment: @mac I've written a hybrid version that uses `itertools` to avoid making the many copies of the list this requires. It turns out to be faster than either this version or my fastest `groupby` version. See my edited answer. Karl - doing the comparisons manually turns out to be the fastest way even though it seemed "naive" to me prior to testing it.

Comment: Can you add some of this information to the answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: This is one of my first Stack Overflow answers, from over 10 years ago, presumably written for 2.x. It's a bit hard to recall the context. Re-reading the question, I would take a completely different approach today.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are using various itertools helpers, and comprehensions, and probably look more "Pythonic". However, a quick timing test I ran showed this generator was a bit faster:

```
_undef = object()

def itersingles(source):
    cur = _undef
    dup = True
    for elem in source:
        if dup:
            if elem != cur:
                cur = elem
                dup = False
        else:
            if elem == cur:
                dup = True
            else:
                yield cur
                cur = elem
    if not dup:
        yield cur

source = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
result = list(itersingles(source))
```

Comment: He repeatedly said he was looking for "concise", "elegant", and "Pythonic" in the question. Even if it didn't, it's not worth having more code to maintain just to shave off a little time unless you know it's your performance bottleneck.

Comment: I guess my aesthetics and definition of "Pythonic" probably doesn't match other peoples'. Personally, I like a simple generator which quickly moves over an iterable, maintaining state along the way; and  it's not something I can easily do in many other languages, whereas it's rather easily expressible in Python. The "sum(1 for i in group) == 1" of one of the other solutions particularly seems wasteful to me (though I don't know of a better way to accomplish that). I agree with your speed vs maintainability point though - a 2x speedup isn't worth it if not a critical point.

Comment: You're right about the `sum`. Inspired by that observation and gnibbler's version, I've come up with a version that seems to be fast for both short and long lists while still taking advantage of `groupby` to keep my custom code minimal.

Comment: This is relatively similar to one of the implementations I tried. Not quite what I was looking for, yet it seems your comments contributed to forge the answer I am going to accept. Thanks and +1! :)

Comment: A version of my latest solution with `islice` and a temp list is only 25% slower than this, and the `chain` version I settled on is only 50% slower. I think of `itertools` as fast, but where they don't quite fit with your needs, a custom generator still seems to perform the best.